# T-SQL Get View query after "AS"

Tags: sql-server, view

I have a view as name "**_report_territories**"

If i run below query

```
EXEC sp_HelpText '_report_territories'
```

Result displays as below screen

[image]

**Question:**

How can i get view query after "**CREATE view [dbo].[_report_territories] AS**" ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean ? the query is shown there already

Comment: where is query after "CREATE view [dbo].[_report_territories] AS"" ?

Comment: it has "as".For another views select query not always come in line 4 sometimes line 5 sometimes line 3 so how can i solve this problem also ?i need spesific , certain query to find select query after AS

Comment: use `charindex` to find the position of `as`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
DECLARE @viewDefiniton nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @viewName nvarchar(max)='_report_territories'
DECLARE @indexOfViewName int
DECLARE @firstASindex int

SELECT @viewDefiniton = VIEW_DEFINITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views where TABLE_NAME = @viewName

SELECT @indexOfViewName = CHARINDEX(@viewName,@viewDefiniton)
SELECT @viewDefiniton = SUBSTRING(@viewDefiniton, @indexOfViewName + LEN(@viewName), LEN(@viewDefiniton))
SELECT @firstASindex = CHARINDEX('as',LOWER(@viewDefiniton))

SELECT @viewDefiniton = SUBSTRING(@viewDefiniton, @firstASindex + 2, LEN(@viewDefiniton))
SELECT @viewDefiniton
```

Comment: Here's hoping your view definition doesn't name its columns, or if it does, that none of them contains the sequence of characters `as`.

Answer (score 1):

Put results of `sp_HelpText` in temporary table, than make it a string and get what you need

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    [Text] nvarchar(max)
)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) =''

INSERT INTO @t 
EXEC sp_HelpText 'vCities'

SELECT @sql =@sql+ [Text]
FROM @t

SELECT SUBSTRING(@sql,1,CHARINDEX('AS',@sql)+ LEN('AS'))
```

Will give you:

```
CREATE View vCities  AS
```

Note: the solution may be unrelevant if view name contains `AS`